# How to list markers only in AGM Circle?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular, Angular Google Maps (agm) and Firebase to list some markers on a map. I have no problem when I'm trying to list all markers that I take from database. I also use a agm-circle on my map. I want to make the markers visible inside this circle, and invisible if outside of it.

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  allMarkers: any;
  lat = 40.927784;
  lng = 29.130245;
  latInput: number;
  longInput: number;
  zoom = 4;
  minZoom = 2.5;
  circleDragEnd() {
    console.log('It\'s alive!');
  }
  mapClicked($event) {
    this.latInput = $event.coords.lat;
    this.longInput = $event.coords.lng;
  }
  addMarker() {
    this.db.collection('/markers').add({ lat: this.latInput, long: this.longInput });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.allMarkers = this.db.collection('/markers').valueChanges();
  }

}
```

And this is my html:

```
<agm-map (mapClick)="mapClicked($event)" [zoom]="4" [minZoom]="2.5" [latitude]="40.927784" [longitude]="29.130245">

  <agm-marker *ngFor="let marker of allMarkers | async" [latitude]="marker.lat" [longitude]="marker.long">
    <agm-info-window>
      <div [innerHTML]="marker.description"></div>
    </agm-info-window>
  </agm-marker>

  <agm-circle [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [radius]="500000" [fillColor]="'purple'" [circleDraggable]="true"
[editable]="true" (dragEnd)="circleDragEnd()">
  </agm-circle>
</agm-map>
<input id="latitude" name="latitude" [(ngModel)]="latInput" type="text" placeholder="latitude">
<input id="longitude" name="longitude" [(ngModel)]="longInput" type="text" placeholder="longitude"><br>
<button (click)="addMarker()">Add Marker!</button>
```

Screenshot of my main page:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JclvN.png)

In this case it should show me the markers on Europe.

Thanks for any help!